# Is there any equivalent to Android's <meta name='viewport' content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi'> for Safari on the iPhone?

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, media-queries

When setting `meta name='viewport' content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi'`, the Android browser and Opera Mobile treats a CSS pixel as a device pixel on my device, leaving my stylesheets unmolested.

Is there any equivalent feature that works in Safari on the iPhone?

On my already mobile-friendly, high-DPI-optimized, media-query-powered web application, I'd really appreciate if the browser left my stylesheets alone.

(My full viewport declaration looks like this: `meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no; target-densitydpi=device-dpi'`)

Answer (score 4):

check this link my be that's help you https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dkx3qtm_22dxsrgcf4

You can write like this

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

check this link also https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2010/the-viewport-metatag-mobile-web-part-1/

Comment: Is there currently any reason to have the "HandheldFriendly" and "MobileOptimized"?  The davidbcalhoun link mentions them in the same section as WML ...

Comment: Latter link is broken

Answer (score -1):

safari support viewport and its attributes but not target-densitydpi.
 please refer this link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW1

Answer (score -1):

It seems that there's no target-densitydpi in safari. For what contents in Viewport of safari, look **[Configuring the Viewport](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW1)**.